# PL/SQL Exception

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Is there a way to catch this error (ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error) into exception? This happens whenever I use string as input. I thought the when others exception will catch it but it wont.

```
DECLARE
    v_order_no NUMBER(10) := &Order_Number;
    var NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO var
    FROM tbl
    WHERE col = v_order_no;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('ndf');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct exception is `VALUE_ERROR`. However, `OTHERS` should catch that error too. The problem with your code is that the exception is being throwed in the declaration section of the block. If you move that assignment after the `BEGIN` you should be able to catch that exception.

```
DECLARE
    v_order_no NUMBER(10);
    var NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    v_order_no := &Order_Number;
    SELECT 1 INTO var
    FROM tbl
    WHERE col = v_order_no;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('ndf');
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('value_error');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would give the assignment its own sub-block so you can guarantee that any validation errors came from that, and not some other part of the code.

I would also enclose `&order_number` within single quotes, in case it is a string which could result in invalid PL/SQL and a compilation error rather than a run-time error.

```
declare
    v_order_no number(10);
    var        number(10);
begin
    begin
        v_order_no := '&order_number';
    exception
        when value_error then
            raise_application_error
            ( -20000, '"&order_number" is not a numeric order number', true);
    end;

    select 1 into var from dual where v_order_no > 0;
    dbms_output.put_line('var = ' || var);

exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('ndf');
end;
```

Now if you run it with `order_number = 123x`, the assignment `v_order_no := '123x'` fails cleanly with:

```
ORA-20000: "123x" is not a numeric order number
ORA-06512: at line 9
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

If you leave it unquoted, it fails compilation with:

```
        v_order_no := 123x
                         *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 26:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "X" when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol "; was inserted before "X" to continue.
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting an additional `Begin` and `END` block should resolve your issue and exception should be caught however what @pablomatico suggest is the correct way of writing a block. Incase you wanted to stick with your own code you can do it as :

```
BEGIN

DECLARE
    v_order_no NUMBER(10) := &Order_Number;
    var NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO var
    FROM tbl
    WHERE col = v_order_no;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('ndf');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
END;

END;
```